# wxTreeListCtrl::Refresh() function is not working in LINUX

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been working on wxWidgets.
I have a problem with `wxTreeListCtrl::Refresh()` function. 
When i click on '+'or'-' to expand or collapse the tree, the tree is getting invisible 
partially and sometimes the content in the tree is getting overlapped.
I thought this is refresh problem so, To fix this issue I have used `wxTreeListCtrl::Refresh()` and I also tried `hide()` and `show()` functions of `wxTreeListctrl`. Still it is behaving as same.

Please, see the image to understand it better.

Operating System: Red hat enterprise Linux 6
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider adding a screenshot and the relevant piece of code.

Comment: If you can reproduce this bug in [the treelist sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/WX_3_0_2/samples/treelist), please open a bug about it because it's clearly not supposed to behave like this. Otherwise try to find what is your code doing differently from the sample.